# How to use the World in mouseClicked() method

Tags: java

I have this line:
        if (Greenfoot.mouseClicked()) 
and I need to add a world as the parameter for the method.

```
 if (Greenfoot.mouseClicked()) 


    {
        World world = getWorld();
        List<Leaf> leaves = world.getObjects(Leaf.class);

        for (Leaf leaf : leaves)
        {
            leaf.changeImage();
        }
    }
```

I need to pass a parameter that allows me to click on the background and change the leaves

Comment: Hello @DrPibbleQuibble. It's not very clear what are you asking. Can you paste the code you're working on or a way to see what you're seeing. What world? What parameter? what method?

Comment: I just don't know the syntax for passing a world or background as a parameter for the mouseClicked method

Comment: Ah, that's a little bit better. I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have the world already in the `getWorld()` method, this method should be defined elsewhere so you probably don't need to pass it.

As for the background and leaved, it seems you also have those. Try to find out more about the definition of that `World` class and see if there's a `setBackground` method. Do the same for the `Leaf` class.

I hope this helps